# Gorm joined tables selects only few field

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have some of this code

```golang
type User struct {
    Id uint `gorm:"column:id"`
    Name string `gorm:"column:name"`
    WalletId uint `gorm:"column:wallet_id"`
    Wallet Wallet `gorm:"foreignkey:club_id"`
}

type Wallet struct {
    Id uint `gorm:"column:id"`
    Money uint `gorm:"column:money"`
    Valute string `gorm:"column:valute"`
}
```

I can query users and their wallets like this

```golang
var users []users
db.Joins("Wallet").Find(&users)
```

this will generate stmt like this

```sql
SELECT user.id, user.name, user.wallet_id, wallet.id, wallet.Money, wallet.Valute from user join wallet on user.wallet_id = wallet.id
```

I need to query all users and only `Valute' field from their wallets

I want to use a gorm like

```
var users []users
db.Joins("Wallet", db.Select("Valute")).Find(&users)
```

for generate this stmt

```sql
SELECT user.id, user.name, user.wallet_id, wallet.Valute from user join wallet on user.wallet_id = wallet.id
```

For choose a wallet field. But it doesn't work at all. Although there is such a use in the function annotation

```
// Joins specify Joins conditions
//     db.Joins("Account").Find(&user)
//     db.Joins("JOIN emails ON emails.user_id = users.id AND emails.email = ?", "jinzhu@example.org").Find(&user)
//     db.Joins("Account", DB.Select("id").Where("user_id = users.id AND name = ?", "someName").Model(&Account{}))
func (db *DB) Joins(query string, args ...interface{}) (tx *DB) {
```

In eager loading by `Preload` i can choose fields like

```
db.Limit(1000).Preload("Wallet",
        func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
            return db.Select("valute")
        },
    ).Find(&users)
```

But this isnt good usage for me, it has a bad perfomance when querying one object. I like to know how can i do the same with `Joins`

PS: I dont want to use a lightweigh model for wallet which queries only valute, i want to use single model for db presentation

Comment: Why do you have a wallet id *and* a wallet inside the user type? How does the resulting select change, when you temporarily remove the `User.Wallet` member?

Comment: @OlafDietsche This is 1to1 relationship, user table physicaly have a field wallet_id and in code Wallet object  to query its by ```Joins``` functionhttps://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins-Preloading

Answer (score 0):

I also want Gorm to support this feature but the best solution I came up with is [Smart Select](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields) but it requires us to manually write query and select fields

```
type CustomUser struct {
    Id uint `gorm:"column:id"`
    Name string `gorm:"column:name"`
    Valute string `gorm:"column:valute"`
}

var users []CustomUser

db.Raw("SELECT users.id, users.name, Wallet.valute FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `wallets` `Wallet` ON `users`.`wallet_id` = `Wallet`.`id`").Find(&users)
```